# Is JPA subquery in FROM clause possible?

Tags: jpa, subquery

I'm having a little problem with JPA. Consider this scenario:

**Table A (id_a)** | **Table B (id_b, id_a)**

What I need is a query like this:

```
Select a.*, c.quantity from A as a, (Select Count(*) as quantity 
from B as b where b.id_a = a.id_a) as c;
```

The thing is that I want to use a jpa query and not a native query, something like this:

```
Select a, c FROM A a, (Select Count(b) FROM B b where a.idA = b.a.idA) c;
```

So then I could iterate from the result (a list of Object[] with a and c in each node) and then assign a.quantity = c;

I repeat, I don't want to use native query, but I found no other way than use redundant data, and add another column to A called Quantity and every time I insert and delete from B, update this column in A.

Please help, I read somewhere that JPA doesn't accept subqueries in Form clause, so, what can I do ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA does not support sub-selects in the FROM clause but EclipseLink 2.4 current milestones builds does have this support.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause

You can probably rewrite the query with just normal joins though.

Maybe,

```
Select a, size(a.bs) from A a
```

or

```
Select a, count(b) from A a join a.bs b group by a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply ! I'll test it as soon as I get back home.

Comment: Hi James, it doesn't work like i wanted, because it retrieves me only the ones that at least have an insert in B. But..... but.... you make me realize  that with JPA, I have the list of B inside A ! so I don't need to make the query, I just have to navigate in the entity ! Thanks so much for your time and shared  knowledges !